# Implementaion of 2-D array in meomory using C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, parameters, implicit-conversion, variable-length-array

Actual ques - To find saddle point in a matrix.

My function call - `find_saddle_point((Arr,rows);`

My function prototype - `void find_saddle_point(int *,int);`

Initialization -

`int rows , column ;`

```
int Arr[rows][column];
```

Warning - 
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘find_saddle_point’ from incompatible pointer   type

My temporary solution - `find_saddle_point(((int *)Arr,rows);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared a two dimensional array.

```
int Arr[rows][column];
```

Used in expressions like in this function call

```
find_saddle_point((Arr,rows);
```

it is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element and has the type `int ( * )[column]`.

However the corresponding parameter has the type `int *` and there is no implicit conversion from the type `int ( * )[column]` to the type `int *`.

```
void find_saddle_point(int *,int);
```

So the compiler issues an error.

As for your temporary "solution"

```
find_saddle_point(((int *)Arr,rows);
```

then it can result in undefined behavior.

Declare the function like

```
void find_saddle_point( int, int, int [][*]);
```

In its definition you shall specify the names of parameters.

```
void find_saddle_point( int row, int column, int [][column])
{
    // ...
}
```

Also for dimensions of arrays it is better to use the type `size_t` instead of the type `int`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void find_saddle_point( size_t, size_t, int a[][*] );

void fill( size_t rows, size_t cols, int a[][cols] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
        {
            a[i][j] = i * cols + j;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t rows = 3;
    size_t cols = 5;

    int a[rows][cols];

    fill( rows, cols, a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%2d ", a[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
 0  1  2  3  4 
 5  6  7  8  9 
10 11 12 13 14
```

Of course the first function declaration in this simple program is redundant and shown only to demonstrate how a function with a parameter that has a type of a variable-length array can be declared.

Comment: Thanks Sir , for such a nice explanation and can you please explain me the reasons of downvotes because I am new to this thing.

Comment: @UtkarshSingh It is not me who down-voted your question. In my opinion it is a normal question of a beginner. I upvoted it.